# div width can't work normal under difference device's width?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I juse find an interesting question! My page can't running well on the `480 * 800` android device. 
The style about the div, I used `width: 15%;` and the other one is `width: 80%;`!

I put my code here.  [the code about my page](http://jsfiddle.net/Jackyhua/6EnAf/).
Why the width with `%` can't work well under the device which has a narrow width screen?
If I want' make it right, what I can do,I don't think give the width `px` is the best way, I even didn't give the `font-size` px?

The picture I get with the test tool Opera-mobile-emulator.
[image]

Comment: try using jQM grids. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/ override `ui-block-x` width using `%` value.

Comment: I give the element's father div `data-role="fieldcontain"`, so if i give them the grid....